# find row from mysql table with multiple parameters (from different columns) using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table as below:

```
--------------------
| Sl | col1 | col2 |   
--------------------
| 1  | data1| msg1 | 
--------------------
| 2  | data2| msg2 | 
--------------------
| 3  | data1| msg3 | 
--------------------
| 4  | data2| msg4 | 
--------------------
| 5  | data1| msg5 | 
--------------------
```

I have a php string `$query = "select * from table WHERE col1='data1'";` , which fetch array 3 results (row number 1, 3, and 5). But i want to get a specific row containing `"data1"` in `"col1"` and `"msg3"` in `"col2"` (which is row number 3) in a single query. How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`AND`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) in the `WHERE` clause to match multiple conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1='data1' AND col2='msg3'
```